# Bigrams and .Join

Tags: python

I got this function and I tried to edit it a little for my purpose 
but instead of getting bigrams I get unigrams. what do I need to add or edit? 
I am really new with python and nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer
from nltk.collocations import BigramCollocationFinder
from nltk.metrics import BigramAssocMeasures
import re


 def get_bigrams(myString):
 tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
 tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(myString)

 bigram_finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(tokens)
 bigrams = bigram_finder.nbest(BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq, 500)

for bigram_tuple in bigrams:
    x = "%s %s" % bigram_tuple
    tokens.append(x)

result = [x for x in tokens if x not in stopwords.words('english') and   len(x) > 3]
 return result


 filename = raw_input('Enter File Name :')
 word_list = re.split('\s+', file(filename).read().lower())


 f=open ('test2.csv', 'w')


for line in word_list:
       features = get_bigrams(line)
       print features
       f.write(str(line))
       f.write("\n")
```

the output of for an exmple "It has been a long time"

```
It   
has   
been  
a  
long  
time
```

Yet I am looking for something like

```
It has
has been
been a 
a long
long time
```

Comment: I mean "It has been a long time" is like [it, has, been, a, long, time] instead of [it has, has been, been a,  a long, long time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is how you tackle the file reading and the line processing:

The following line gives you a list of words (as the name suggests)

```
word_list = re.split('\s+', file(filename).read().lower())
```

but later you treat each single word as a line:

```
for line in word_list:
```

This just means that your code can simply not work.

If I understand you correctly you might want to change file reading in the following way:

```
filename = raw_input('Enter File Name :')
lines = file(filename).readlines()

f = open('test2.csv', 'w')

for line in lines:
    features = get_bigrams(line)
    # do more things
```

Answer (score 1):

Nltk seems like overkill here. Why not just do:

```
def pairs(seq):
    return zip(seq, seq[1:])

s = "It has been a long time"
words = s.split()
for bigram in pairs(words):
    print bigram
```

Result:

```
('It', 'has')
('has', 'been')
('been', 'a')
('a', 'long')
('long', 'time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `get_bigrams` seems to work for me so I think the problem is your file or the way you read it.
By the way, Id like to suggest a shorter code for `get_bigrams`:

```
import nltk

def get_bigrams(sentence):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    return zip(tokens, tokens[1:])
```

Use:

```
>>> [' '.join(b) for b in get_bigrams("It has been a long time")]
['It has', 'has been', 'been a', 'a long', 'long time']
```